# Bounds on block error probability based on bit error probability for ldpc

Tags: coding-theory

If one has the bit error probability $P_b^e$ of a LDPC ensemble on a BEC or BSC using belief propagation decoding, is there any bound on the block error probability $P_B^e$ based on the bit error probability?

Comment: My very limited experience suggests that this may be difficult in general. With some LDPC codes only very few bits were in error after belief propagation (on some occasions more iterations might have helped - I don't remember). But, with some other LDPC codes (relatively high rate IIRC) there were usually hundreds of erroneous bits in a an erroneous block. So I have the impression that it is difficult to meaningfully relate the two. I take it running a sim is not an option for you?

Comment: Scratch the suggestion to run a sim. You did say *ensemble* :-)